# Field Collapsing and Grouping in Solr 3.2

Tags: solr

Does anybody know if Field Collapsing and Grouping is available in Solr 3.2.
I mean directly available, not as a patch.

I have read conflicting statements about it...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natively supported collapsing is not available in Solr 3.2 and is only expected to appear in version 4.

Answer (score 1):

released in Solr/Lucene 3.3 a few days ago